# NVARCHAR2 equation issue in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, nls

**Env:**

Oracle version: Release 10.2.0.1.0
Server: Windows XP

**Language in oracle:**

```
select userenv('language') from dual;
```

Result:
CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8

**Table structure:**

PARTY_ID NVARCHAR2(50)
PARTY_TYPE NVARCHAR2(50)

**Data in the table:**

```
PARTY_ID | PARTY_TYPE
---------+-----------
BEST     | C    
WILL     | C
```

**SQL1:**

```
SELECT  * FROM cc_party  
WHERE party_type = 'C'
```

Result:

nothing

**SQL1:**

```
SELECT  * FROM cc_party  
WHERE party_type = 'C' or party_type = 'C'
```

Result:

```
PARTY_ID | PARTY_TYPE
---------+-----------
BEST     | C    
WILL     | C
```

**Question:**

Why I can not select data by `party_type = 'C'` (SQL1) ? Is there some special things about NVARCHAR2 ?

If I update the where clause to `party_type = 'C' or party_type = 'C'` (SQL2), I can get the result. It makes me confused. I want to know why the result come out when I added or clause.

Comment: Are those 'C's the same or different 'C's?

Comment: Also, why did you make this Community Wiki?  It's not teh sort of question which fits CW.

Comment: SELECT DUMP(party_type) FROM cc_party will show you the internal structure of the string. My guess is that the column has an 'exotic' character that looks like a 'C'. But you can also get odd effects with function-based indexes.

Comment: Query: 
select dump(party_type), dump('C') from party where trim(party_type) = 'C' 
Result:
Typ=1 Len=2: 0,67 | Typ=96 Len=1: 67

Comment: It seems that the data has space in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,and tell me the result

SELECT * FROM cc_party WHERE trim(party_type) = 'C'

Comment: If I use trim with party_type, I can get the result.